# Routing between network adapters on Windows Enterprise

Tags: windows, networking, routing, nat, network-adapter

I have 2 network adapters, one is "Mobile Broadcast Network" (10.123.1.23) and the other is LAN (192.168.1.1).

I need to give the LAN adapter access to the cellular internet and I've tried to use the Windows "Internet Connection Sharing" (ICS) but it's very unstable and I can't get it to work properly.

After trying [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1153511) I can see that requests from the LAN going out through the cellular (using [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)) but there is no response back at all.

And when adding these routes I have no access to the LAN from localhost :

```
route -p ADD 10.123.1.23 MASK 255.255.255.252 192.168.1.1
route -p ADD 192.168.1.0 MASK 255.255.254.0 10.123.1.23
```

Here is the route table:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      10.123.1.24      10.123.1.23    306
      10.123.1.22  255.255.255.252         On-link       10.123.1.23    306
      10.123.1.23  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.123.1.23    306
      10.123.1.25  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.123.1.23    306
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link   169.254.244.220    291
  169.254.244.220  255.255.255.255         On-link   169.254.244.220    291
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link   169.254.244.220    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link   169.254.244.220    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.123.1.23    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link   169.254.244.220    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.123.1.23    306
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
      10.123.1.23  255.255.255.252      192.168.1.1       1
      192.168.1.0    255.255.254.0      10.123.1.23       1
===========================================================================
```

(The real cellular IP replaced with "10.123.1.23")

P.S. I found how to configure "NAT and Routing" on Windows Server, but I don't have the same tools on Windows Enterprise.

**UPDATE:**

I found the right answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1586673/1240974).

Is it possible to implement this solution using routing on my side?
(because the internet connection is from a cellular network provider and not a router)

Comment: Which tools are you missing on Windows Enterprise?

Comment: For example he doing here [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bgpEOc6WHFo) something similar to what I need. but he use the the Server Manager on the Windows Server (2019).

Comment: That video is 9 minutes long. Can you just list the tools?

Comment: He installing there these things via the "Server Manager": "Remote Access", "DirectAccess and VPN (RAS)" and "Routing". after that he simply just configuring a NAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I succeeded with it.

I had to install NAT.

At first I tried to use the `netsh routing ip nat` but when I tried the command `add interface Cellular full` I got these 2 error lines:

```
An interface with this name is not registered with the router.
An interface with this name is not registered with the router.
```

Thanks to the usefull information [here](https://colinux.fandom.com/wiki/Step_by_step_in_XP) I realized that it probably doesn't work well with MBN adapter (Cellular).

I have installed [NAT32](https://www.nat32.com/) and it is almost perfect now.